# sort data in a table by column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to sort the data from a mysql database when clinking in the header of a html table. I wrote this code:

```
$username = $_SESSION['username']; // gets the username

echo "<table class='normal_table'>";

$new_word = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_word WHERE username='$username'");
$new_word2 = mysql_query($new_word);

echo " 

<tr>
<th><a href='test.php?sort=cz'>Czech:</a></th>
<th><a href='test.php?sort=en'>English:</a></th>
<tr>";

if ($_GET['sort'] == 'cz')
{
 $new_word .= " ORDER BY cz";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'en')
{
 $new_word .= " ORDER BY en";
}

while($new_word2 = mysql_fetch_array($new_word)){

echo "
<tr>
<td> ".$new_word2['cz']."</td>
<td>".$new_word2['en']."</td>
</tr>

"; }

echo "</table>";
```

But on the screen does not appear any data whatsoever :( What I did wrong?

Comment: You queried your database without passing the ORDER BY clause to your query.

Comment: You need to append the `$new word` to the query BEFORE you run `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing your query at

```
$new_word = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM new_word WHERE username='$username'");
```

then attempting to appen to that query object at

```
$new_word .= " ORDER BY en";
```

You need to build the query string first

so

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM new_word WHERE username='$username'"
```

append your `ORDER BY`

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY en";
```

then execute

```
$new_word = mysql_query($sql);
```

EDIT: Also remove `$new_word2 = mysql_query($new_word);` and change your while to use `$new_world` as Uttam Kadam says in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13818446/50866)

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_word2 = mysql_query($new_word); //$new_word wrong
```

Remove this line this is extra.